# Expected value and memoryless property of Geometric

Tags: probability, dice

When you roll a fair 6 sided die, the expected number of rolls to get a certain number (say 6) is 6. But the memoryless property says that if you roll any amount of non-6 numbers then you'd still expect to have 6 more rolls until you see 6.

What if you wanted to bet on how many rolls it would take to get 6 and you were allowed to change your guess after each roll (as long as it hasn't turned up 6 yet and the number of rolls hasn't reached your guess). So you'd guess 6 rolls at the start, and the dice comes up a 4. Do you update your guess to 7 rolls total or keep the initial guess? The memoryless says we should update but if you kept changing your guess to be 6 rolls from the current roll you'd never win! What would be the optimal strategy here?

Comment: Suppose your initial guess is $6$ rolls, and a $4$ comes up. If you always update on a miss, then you change your guess to $6$ more rolls once the $4$ appears. But it's silly to say "you never win" since a $6$ might appear on the very next roll.

Comment: But if a 6 appears on the next roll then you would lose because that would be two rolls total and you would have updated your guess to 7 rolls total?

Comment: Doesn't the initial guess of $6$ mean that you win if a $6$ appears _within_ the next $6$ rolls?

Comment: No sorry I meant it has to be on the 6th roll

Comment: I doubt that that was the intended rule, but if so, an optimal first guess is $1$, and you should always update on a miss by adding $1$.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Is it from a book?

Comment: No it's just something I was wondering, and I have the rule that you're only allowed to change if the number of rolls hasn't reached your guess and it hasn't come up a 6 yet

Comment: So if you make an initial guess of $1$, and the first roll is $6$, you win, but if the first roll is not a $6$, then you can't update (hence you lose)?

Comment: Yes you would lose then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification of the rules in the comments, if you guess more than $1$, and always update on a miss by adding more than $1$, then as you noted, you will never win.

It follows that in order to win, at some point, you must wait it out.

Based on that, it's clear that no strategy can yield a probability of winning *more* than $1/6$.

If your initial guess is $1$, then you win with probability $1/6$.

If your initial guess is more than $1$, then if a $6$ appears on the first roll, you lose, hence no strategy with an initial guess of more than $1$ has a winning probability more than $(5/6){\,\cdot\,}(1/6)=5/36$.

It follows that the unique optimal strategy is to make an initial guess of $1$ (and then you win or lose based on the result of the first roll).

Comment: I see, but if the expected value is 6 why wouldn't you guess 6? I know the odds aren't in your favor but I thought that's what the implication of expected value was? That it would take 6 rolls to get a 6 on average?

Comment: The expected value of $6$ represents the average number of rolls _until_ you get a $6$, but getting a $6$ on the $6$-th roll has the same probability, namely $(1/6)$, as getting a $6$ on the first roll (or any specified roll). But with the rules you specified, since the first occurrence of a $6$ ends the game, if you guess $6$ and wait it out, the probability of winning is $(5/6)^5{\,\cdot\,}(1/6)\approx (1/15)$ (which is much less than $1/6$).